# Terraform remote-exec fails with permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm attempting to use the remote-exec provisioner to check if the user data on a new AWS ec2 instance has finished but I keep getting a permission denied error.

The error is.

```
bash: /tmp/terraform_409380328.sh: Permission denied
```

We are using Terraform version 10.8

Can anyone help?

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
        "set -x",
        "chmod +x /tmp/*sh",
        "/bin/bash -c \"timeout 300 sed '/finished-user-data/q' <(tail /var/lib/cloud/data/result.json)\"",
    ]
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = "${var.user}"
      private_key = "${file("${var.private_key}")}"
      agent = false
    }
  }
```

Comment: which version of terraform you are using? did you specify the right user? I am able to run the above with out any error.

Comment: Terraform version 10.8
We are using ec2-user.
The same user and key are being used with a file provisioner which is working fine.

Answer (score 6):

I found the issue was that our base image (ami) is hardened and that stops scripts from running from /tmp, which is what terraform is trying to do.

By using the script_path option I was able to instruct terraform to create and run the script in a different directory.

I could then use the cloud-init status --wait command to wait until user data was finished.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "sudo cloud-init status --wait",
  ]
connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "${var.user}"
    private_key = "${file("${var.private_key}")}"
    agent = false
    script_path = "/home/${var.user}/user-data-check.sh"
  }
}
```

Comment: script_path trick did it for me on k3os, thank you! Used /home/rancher...

Answer (score 0):

Terraform's `remote-exec` provisioner requires `/tmp` to be mounted in a way that allows executable permissions. If you have it mounted as `noexec` then the `remote-exec` provisioner will not work.

For EC2 instances, a more robust option is to pass data from Terraform to the EC2 instance using the `user_data` mechanism. If your AMI contains `cloud-init` then you can set `user_data` to be a shell script and then `cloud-init` will run that script automatically on boot, without any need for Terraform to SSH into the system and run any additional commands. Other major cloud compute systems have similar features.

Terraform offers provisioners only as a last resort for when other options are unavailable, such as when using Terraform with legacy compute systems that do not have a feature comparable to EC2's `user_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like RickBowden but I changed just the directory

```
resource "aws_instance" "node" {
  ami           = var.ami_id
  count         = var.count
  instance_type = var.type
[...]
  user_data = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
[...]
EOF
}

resource "null_resource" "join_cluster" {
```

[...]

```
  # Connection to the nodes. Security hardening doesn't allow executions from /tmp directory
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = local.rest[count.index % local.rest_count]
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = var.ssh_key
    agent       = false
    script_path = "/home/ubuntu/terraform_%RAND%.sh"
  }
```

[...]

```
  depends_on = [aws_instance.node]
}
```